# reading excel 2003(.xls) in c#

Tags: c#, excel

i have  an issue in reading excel 2003  format file (xls).

**i am using vs2008 with  windows 7. and 64 bit   Processor**

the below  code  works  fine  if i send an excel 2007 format file (.xlsx)
i have office 2007  been  installed in my system.

here i have  add refrence

```
Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.dll
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0.dll
```

```c#
#region ExcelToDataTableChild

/// <summary>
/// Excel To DataTable for   attendance employee
/// </summary>
/// <param name="strfilelocation"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public  DataTable ExcelToDataTableChild(string strfilelocation, string strfilename)
{
    OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection();
    DataTable dtPatterns = new DataTable();
    string excelConnStr = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetExtension(@strfilelocation);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand(); OleDbDataAdapter excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        
        #region Check FileExtension
        
        if (fileName.Equals(".xlsx"))
        {
            excelConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + strfilelocation + "; Extended Properties =Excel 8.0;";
        }
        if (fileName.Equals(".xls"))
        {
            excelConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + strfilelocation + "; Extended     Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        }
        
        #endregion
                

        excelConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr);
        excelConn.Open();
        //excelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT `Employee Name` as PATTERN FROM [sheet1$]", excelConn);
        excelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]", excelConn);
        excelDataAdapter.SelectCommand = excelCommand;
        excelDataAdapter.Fill(dtPatterns);
        dtPatterns.TableName = "EmpList";
        ds.Tables.Add(dtPatterns);
        dtPatterns.AcceptChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLogError(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        excelConn.Close();
    }
    return dtPatterns;
}

#endregion
```

the above  code  works   fine in system for excel 2003(.xls) where i am using Xp,VS 2008.

the code   works  fine  where i am  able  to read excel 2003 data with no issue.

but the  same  code  fails in windows 7, 64  bit  proocessor

any help  how i can  solve the problem would be great.

thanks
prince

Answer (score 2):

The ACE provider is 32-bit and your application should be compiled in 32-bit mode to use it. Here's a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/58c4c61e-fa86-4809-bf7d-21bacb055d3e/) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)** for reading Excel file in applications.

http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Comment: Koogra is great for reading excel. It does not need office installed. Using it with success.

Comment: Everybody says use exceldatareader, use koogra. It's cool! But I could find any samples or some decent documentation. Can you guys post a link with a nice example? I'm having trouble to get DateTime values from excel with exceldatareader.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead.